# Firebase / iOS: Disable persistence storage for some paths?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't want Firebase in some views to use the persistence storage. Unfortunately disabling / enabling in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidDisappear` does not work, because it has to be done before using the first reference.

Is this possible?